# search disappears when adding new column to datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, datatables

Why does the search box disappear when adding new columns in the HTML of datatables? I'm trying to convert something to jquery and data tables, but cannot figure out how to add new data besides for data in the pre-existing settings that I got when I downloaded the program. The website isn't very clear on how to add new columns...

http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

```
<div id="demo">
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
        <th>new column</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to load whole table with all columns and just hide certain columns? That would be most efficient.

Comment: I'm not at that point yet. I'm just trying to add one measly column. Even if I add new data in the rows, it just disappears. I think it has something to do with the datatables.js For clarification, I can edit the existing data just fine, adding new ones is a pain.

Comment: It's Right here: http://jsfiddle.net/JJF3/LwhUm/ I just tried to make the demo work locally.